# Geometric proof of complex number equation

Tags: complex-analysis

Use geometric reasoning to find a value for $θ \in [−\pi, 0]$ satisfying $|e^{iθ} − 1| =\sqrt2$.

So far I have converted to exponential form as $|\cos \theta + i\sin \theta -1|=\sqrt2$.

I'm having trouble proceeding any further.

Comment: We want a point on the standard unit circle which is at distance $\sqrt{2}$ from $1$. So we want $x^2+y^2=1$, $(x-1)^2+y^2=2$. Subtract.

Comment: $e^{i\theta}$ lies in the unit circle, $|z-w|$ is the distance between $z$ and $w$, and $\sqrt{2}$ can be seen as the length of the diagonal of a square of side 1.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $(\cos \theta - 1)^2 + \sin^2 \theta = 2$

Answer (score 1):

look at the unit circle $|z| = 1$ and consider the points $O = 0, A = 1$ and the point $P = e^{i\theta}.$ the number $e^{i\theta} - 1$ represents the complex number $AP$  in the isosceles triangle $OP = OA = 1, AP = \sqrt 2.$  that means  $\angle AOP=90^\circ$. if you want it in the negative half plane $\theta = -90^\circ$

Answer (score 1):

Algebraically, you can take the modulus of $e^{i\theta}-1$ and solve it that way. That is,
$$|e^{i\theta}-1| = \sqrt{(e^{i\theta}-1)(e^{-i\theta}-1)} =\sqrt{2-e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}.$$
If you make the "$\textrm{cis}(\pm\theta)$" substitution now, you should be able to find $\theta$ without too much trouble. Since you're supposed to use "geometric intuition" though, here's a graphical solution: In the complex plane, $e^{i\theta}$ with $\theta\in [-\pi, 0]$ sweeps out the bottom semicircle. The point $1$ corresponds to $(1,0)$ in the plane (since it has complex part $0$). Now since $|\cdot|$ computes lengths, you need to find the point on the unit circle thats $\sqrt{2}$ from the point on the real axis. It should be pretty clear that the line connecting $e^{-i\pi/2} = (0,-1)$ and $(1,0)$ has length $\sqrt{2}$ (this is a $90$-$45$-$45$ isosceles triangle with legs of length $1$, so the hypotenuse has length $\sqrt{2}$).